# If $|z+w|=|z-w|$ prove that $\arg(z)- \arg(w)=\pi/2; z ,w\in\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have done this already by using a parallelogram but I want someone to post the proof so I can check my work. If you are able to post more than one method please do

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant $|z+w|=|z-w|$. Then , seeing $|z+w|=|z-(-w)|$ as the distance from $z$ to $-w$, $z$ is the set of points equidistant from 
$w$ and -$w$.